# Var undefined en servicio

Tags: angular, ionic

estoy teniendo problemas para poder recuperar una variable de una clase servicio hacia un componente. El problema esta comentado en la función isAuthenticated() del archivo app.component.ts

autentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ToastController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  authState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public token : string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private storage: Storage,
    private platform: Platform,
    public toastController: ToastController
  ){
    this.ifLoggedIn();
  }

  async ifLoggedIn() {
    await this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
      if(token){
        this.authState.next(true);
        this.token = token;
        console.log(this.token); //El token existe en este punto
      }
    });
  }

  login(){
    this.storage.set('token', 'asd123asdasd12354151asd').then((response) => {
      this.router.navigate(['app/inicio']);
      this.authState.next(true);
    });
  }

  logout(){
    this.storage.remove('token').then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['app/inicio']);
      this.authState.next(false);
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated(){
    return this.authState.value;
  }

  getToken(){
    return this.token;
  }



}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Events, MenuController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './side-menu/styles/side-menu.scss',
    './side-menu/styles/side-menu.shell.scss',
    './side-menu/styles/side-menu.responsive.scss'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  isAuth : boolean;

  constructor(
    public auth : AuthenticationService,
    private events: Events,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.isAuthenticated();
    });
    //this.isAuthenticated();
  }

  isAuthenticated(){
    console.log(this.auth.getToken()); // devuelve un "undefined"
    console.log(this.auth.token); // devuelve un "undefined"
    console.log(this.auth); // y este es el más curioso devuelve el objeto auth y dentro del objeto se ve seteado el token y no puedo acceder a él de las formas anteriormente dichas.....
  }

  logOut(){
    this.auth.logout();
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estoy planteando mal? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Primero, deberías usar `subscribe` para acceder al valor del Observable. Segundo, es posible que `storage.get('token')` nunca te devuelve un valor, por ende, `token` queda como `undefined`.

Comment: @gugadev el valor del token en `storage.get('token').then()` si que lo obtiene y lo seteo a una variable publica de la clase

Comment: La llamada a `ifLoggedIn()` es asíncrona. Tienes que esperar a que termine para que puedas ver tus resultados. Puedes usar una promesa para su ejecución.

Comment: Buenas gracias @Angel lo se, con ello estaba intentando hacer q a la hora de crear el objeto espere a ello , pero no lo hace. No hay forma de crear un objeto de forma asyncrona y poder acceder a su variable ya procesada?

Comment: Mete esa función en una promesa y llámala con el subscribe desde app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

La consola del navegador no es fiable. Prueba los siguientes pasos:

1. Abre las DevTools (la consola) y escribe lo siguiente:

   ```
   let test = [ 2,4,6,8,10,12]
   ```
2. Escribe en consola

   ```
   test
   ```

   Te aparecerá algo como una flecha seguida del texto:

   ```
   (6) [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
   ```

   No des a la flecha (no despliegues el array)
3. Escribe a continuación

   ```
   test.push(14);
   ```
4. Ahora despliega la flecha anterior, verás algo como

   ```
   (6) [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
   0: 2
   1: 4
   2: 6
   3: 8
   4: 10
   5: 12
   6: 14
   length: 7
   __proto__: Array(0)
   ```

Esto es porque la consola calcula los valores **bajo demanda**, por tanto siempre verás el valor actualizado al momento de desplegar.

#### Tu problema

Cuando la consola escribe `undefined`, la promesa que rellena el token aún no se ha cumplido.
Cuando despliegas el objeto, unas décimas de segundo después, la promesa se ha cumplido y la propiedad `token` ya tiene un valor.
Si te fijas, en tu propia imagen se ve algo similar: las propiedades de AuthenticationService están listadas entre las llaves y **no** incluyen `token`. Si fuese porque no caben todas, verías una elipsis justo antes de la llave de cierre:

```
window
Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
```

Comment: Buenas Pablo gracias , he cambiado las posiciones de los logs , he subido una nueva imagen , he puesto primero el objeto y como veras esta seteado el token y despues tampoco lo puedo acceder. Creo que esto demuestra que la consola en este caso no es el problema. Mil gracias.